# Paypal Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout) Magneto 1.9.1.1 Auto Invoice After payment and change status to complete

Tags: php, magento, paypal-ipn, paypal

I am selling downloadable product in my website . There is payment method only Paypal Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout) included . 
When customer checkout the order the order status is in processing . I want it Pending until i approve from admin. But it is in processing . When customer redirect to paypal and complete their payment . The status automatically change into complete and invoice auto created . i want to stop paypal to create invoice and order status in pending . i want it to change manually or creating invoic.

Anybody can help will? 
Suggestion also appreciable.

Thanks in advance guys .

Answer (score 0):

In the backend order status menu you'll need to create another order status called paid, or payment received then you set that as the default when magento detects that payment has been received

Comment: I tried . But still its set to complete after payment through paypal .